# How to simulate a click on a Font Awesome Icon using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm testing through Jest and am trying to test the click on a Font Awesome Icon. I've tried different ways to find the 'node', but I get the error that "Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead." Any insight would be helpful.

The error I get when I try different inputs to `component.find()` is: `Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`

***StringEditor***

```
const clearInput = () => {
    onRemove()
}

render (
    ...
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fal', 'times-circle']} className="clear-button" 
    onClick={clearInput} /> : null`
)
```

`onRemove` is a callback function.

```
it('should call clearInput thus onRemove', () =>{

    const onRemove= jest.fn()
    const component = mount(<StringEditor {...defaultProps}  onRemove={onRemove} />)
    component.find('<dont know what to put>').simulate('click')
    expect(saveValueFn).toBeCalled()
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
it('should call clearInput thus onRemove', () =>{
    const onRemove= jest.fn()
    const component = mount(<StringEditor {...defaultProps}  onRemove={onRemove} />)
    component.find({ className: "clear-button" }).simulate('click');
    expect(clearInput).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: It seems to have detected the node, but the value is `null` despite hard coding content into it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Object Property Selector: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#4-object-property-selector

Or a React Component Constructor: https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#2-a-react-component-constructor